# I'm on Unity 2017 LTS now. To upgrade, should I go right to 2019 LTS or should I go through 2018 LTS first?

Tags: unity-game-engine

My end goal is to keep up with upgrades and stay on the latest LTS. I'm concerned about not having a lot of time left for 2018 LTS. If doing the upgrades incrementally is helpful, I'll do that regardless. If a 2018 upgrade introduces problems that I wouldn't have to address with a direct to 2019 upgrade, I may be interested in skipping 2018. I realize 2019 LTS isn't out at the moment, but it should be any time now.

Also, is it ever helpful to make a new project and move my existing assets over gradually in logical pieces? Or is it always best to just open the existing project with the new version (after a back up) and start tackling errors? TIA

Comment: You could always make a copy of an existing working project and go right for the latest version and see if any problems pop up and try fixing them from there.With this approach you don't need an intermediate version.

Comment: First, carefully read the release notes and be sure you can live with the things that have changed. 2019 drops support for older iOS and Android versions that you may have existing players on. When you do choose a version to upgrade to be sure to delete your Library directory before opening the project in the new editor. I've seen quite a few WTF type problems just go away because of that simple step where the old Library just confused Unity. Definitely use source control or make a backup (or more than one) before you open the project with a new editor.

Answer (score 2):

Doing upgrades incrementally (keeping up with minor version changes) is only reccomended if you need a feature introduced in a specific minor version. Normally moving from LTS version to the next is fine for a long running project.

You won't really be saving yourself any work by going through 2018 first (although it's likely it doesn't hurt much either if you're already on 2017.4.x). If there isn't any particular reason you're thinking about upgrading you can probably stay on 2017 LTS version until 2019 LTS is out.

As for the upgrade process itself, opening the project in the new editor version and fixing any errors that pop up is the standard approach. The way you mention "backing up first" makes me feel the need to add: you should try using some form of source control. Git and Unity work quite well together, and if anything goes wrong with your upgrade, you can always roll back to a stable commit.

Comment: We're just trying to stay on the latest stable code base in general. Newer versions are appealing because of the added features and the extra length of Unity support. By the time I get to the 2018 upgrade we'd probably have something like 6 months of support left before I'm forced into another upgrade. So I was thinking of going for it all at once. We're using SVN for version control by the way.

Comment: Sounds like you're probably fine to wait until 2019.4.x then.